# $filter inside $reduce or inside $map from array without unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need some help:
I want to optimize this query to be faster , it need to filter by events.eventType:"log" all docs with server:"strong" , but without separate unwind & filter stages , maybe somehow inside the $reduce stage to add $filter.

example single document:

```
 {
 server: "strong",
 events: [
  {
    eventType: "log",
    createdAt: "2022-01-23T10:26:11.214Z",
    visitorInfo: {
      visitorId: "JohnID"
    }
  }
```

current aggregation  query:

```
   db.collection.aggregate([
   {
    $match: {
    server: "strong"
    }
   },
   {
    $project: {
     total: {
      $reduce: {
      input: "$events",
      initialValue: {
        visitor: [],
        uniquevisitor: []
      },
      in: {
        visitor: {
          $concatArrays: [
            "$$value.visitor",
            [
              "$$this.visitorInfo.visitorId"
            ]
          ]
        },
        uniquevisitor: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $in: [
                "$$this.visitorInfo.visitorId",
                "$$value.uniquevisitor"
              ]
            },
            "$$value.uniquevisitor",
            {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value.uniquevisitor",
                [
                  "$$this.visitorInfo.visitorId"
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
          }
        }
       }
      }
    }
    }
    ])
```

expected output , two lists with unique visitorId & list of all visitorId:

```
 [
{
"total": {
  "uniquevisitor": [
    "JohnID"
  ],
  "visitor": [
    "JohnID",
    "JohnID"
  ]
}
```

}
]

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6AcrcdmtQt5)

In the example query no filter is added for events.eventType:"log" , how can this be implemented without $unwind?

Comment: (1) One of things is include this filter within the initial match stage - this helps select only documents where at least there is one match for `events.eventType:"log"` (this is assuming that there can be documents without any `events.eventType: ''log'`). (2) Faster query - you have the option to define index on the fields in the initial match stage. (3) The array operators, `$filter`, `$map` and `$reduce` can be nested or used together - for example you can use the `$let` to perform array operations in multiple steps within the same `$addFields` stage.

Comment: This is what I try to achieve the nested $filter in $map or $reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this approach is more optimized than yours but might be this will help,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `events` and filter by `eventType`
- `$let` to declare a variable `events` and store the above filters result
- return array of `visitor` by using dot notation `$$events.visitorInfo.visitorId`
- return array of unique visitor `uniquevisitor` by using dot notation `$$events.visitorInfo.visitorId` and `$setUnion` operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { server: "strong" } },
  {
    $project: {
      total: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            events: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$events",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$this.eventType", "log"] }
              }
            }
          },
          in: {
            visitor: "$$events.visitorInfo.visitorId",
            uniquevisitor: {
              $setUnion: "$$events.visitorInfo.visitorId"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_q2-xXAOa59)

---

Or similar approach without `$let` and two `$project` stages,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { server: "strong" } },
  {
    $project: {
      events: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$events",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.eventType", "log"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      total: {
        visitor: "$events.visitorInfo.visitorId",
        uniquevisitor: {
          $setUnion: "$events.visitorInfo.visitorId"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Kp12X0VQgv)

Answer (score -1):

You can use filtered events directly as input to reduce stage. For e.g. in my case I had an array of offers - with some of them as special user's. I wanted to find the best among those with a valid user. Here is what I did in $project:

```
  bestOffer: {
$reduce: {
  input: {$filter: {
input: '$offers', as: 'offer',
cond: {$gt: ['$$offer.rfqUser',{}]}
}},
  initialValue: {'yield': 0},
  in: {
    $cond: [              {
      '$gte': ['$$this.yield', '$$value.yield']},
      '$$this', '$$value'
    ]
  }
}
```

},

Comment: How does this add a new value on top of [turivishal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70990082/14732669)? The concept is already mentioned there and you are not even providing an example customized to OP's scenario.